# Timeout connecting to Cassandra cluster from python

Tags: python, cassandra

I am getting the following error trying to connect to Cassandra using the `cassandra-driver` 2.1.4 library (with a real IP instead of stars of course):

```
NoHostAvailable: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'**.**.**.**': 
OperationTimedOut('errors=None, last_host=None',), '**.**.**.**': 
OperationTimedOut('errors=None, last_host=None',)})
```

Code to connect:

```
Database.history = Cluster(
    ip_list.split(","),
    auth_provider=PlainTextAuthProvider(
        username=u,
        password=p
    )
).connect(k)
```

Now the weirdness: I can connect totally fine from this same box using Datastax DevCenter on the same default port.  If I edit those IPs to be bogus, I get a different error (saying it couldn't connect to the host instead of a timeout).  If I edit the username/password to be bogus, I get an auth error.

So clearly I'm *sort of* connecting, but for some reason I can't actually get a working connection in Python.

Also, I have this same code running on a remote box successfully.  So it has to be something weird with my local python or something.

Comment: When you refer to 'query editor' are you referencing DevCenter?  Also what version of cassandra are you attempting to connect to?  Do you get any additional logging information that may be helpful to us?   It might be worth enabling debug logging: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/developer/python-driver/2.1/python-driver/reference/enablingDebugLevelLogging.html

Comment: I'm running Cassandra 2.1.2.  Enabling logging like that provided no additional output.

EDIT: And yes, I'm using DevCenter to connect successfully.

Comment: Also worth noting may be that I have this same code running on another box remotely that is successfully connecting.

Comment: Couldn't get debug logging working reasonably, but I managed to hack it up so I could read it at least.  The last thing I see before the error is

[control connection] Established new connection <LibevConnection(29244048) ***.***.**.**:9042>, registering watchers and refreshing schema and topology

Answer (score 1):

There is some sort of timing issue in the `cassandra-driver` connection code, which is not resolved by increasing the connection or request timeouts. While investigating what the problem might be, I stumbled across this hacky workaround, which might be of use to someone else stuck at this same roadblock:

```
import logging
logging.getLogger().addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

Put the above code at the top of your script. My guess is, it adds just enough lag into the client-side code that it resolves the timing issue, at the price of some unnecessary log messages being printed to stderr.